# How do I display data in a table structure?

Tags: discussion, markdown, tables

I want to explain a MySQL table structure, and I used `<dt>` and `<dl>`.

But I could see other posts having a neat table display of their examples

How do I code a table-like structure in a question's textarea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can display data in table structure like this:

```
id | stationname | total
-------------------------
 1 | Khar        | 5
 2 | SantaCruz   | 3
 3 | Sion        | 2
 4 | VT          | 1
 5 | newFort     | 3
 6 | Bandra      | 2
 7 | Worli       | 1
 8 | Sanpada     | 3
 9 | Joe         | 2
10 | Sally       | 1
11 | Elphiston   | 2
12 | Currey Road | 1
```

Here you need to write your data in normal table structure (like writing it on notepad.). Then you just need to give them code sample appearance. (By <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>).

Note: You can use some external tools for that such as:

- [Asciiflow](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)
- [ASCII table](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)
- [etc...](https://www.google.com/search?q=ascii+table+generator)

Comment: you mean with tabs and spaces in notepad or using tags of html?

Comment: i tried it works with tabs or even spaces... that is how i had created previously but as i have said i could see more formatted neat tables.

Comment: @JayapalChandran - Just click on `edit` button of this answer and see how the table is formatted.